# how to make a class keep in that ul li tag after mouseover listener out from that div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

i am trying to make option select which use DOM to choose the option in div
here is my dropdown html : so I make this div scrollable and have event listener up and down

then up and down on focus , I will add class **hover** which gonna have background-color
also when mouse over to that LI tag, gonna add that class as well

but after mouse out from the box it keep deleted the class on muy function

how to make that class steady/keep in that li tag after i am out from the box ?

```js
var active = document.querySelector(".hover") || document.querySelector(".dropdownItemContainer li");

document.addEventListener("keydown",handler);
document.addEventListener("mouseover",handler);

function handler(e){
        active.classList.remove("hover");
    if (e.which == 40){
        active = active.nextElementSibling || active;
    }else if (e.which == 38){      
        active = active.previousElementSibling || active;
    }else{
        active = e.target;
    }
        active.classList.add("hover");
}
```

```css
ul.dropdownItemContainer li.hover {
  background-color: #8284e6;
}

.dropdown-test {
   height: 90px;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown-test">
  <ul class="dropdownItemContainer">
    <li class="hover">Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

can anyone help to explain also and using javascript only? please

Answer (score 1):

The "problem" is the script will delete hover class when you hover another element, you need to check if this element is into this  for example (you can use your method instead) i add `data-attribute` and check if have this `data-checker` into script, if not don't do nothing.

```js
var active = document.querySelector(".hover") || document.querySelector(".dropdownItemContainer li");

document.addEventListener("keydown", handler);
document.addEventListener("mouseover", handler);

function handler(e) {
  if (e.target.hasAttribute("data-checker")) {
    active.classList.remove("hover");
    if (e.which == 40) {
      active = active.nextElementSibling || active;
    } else if (e.which == 38) {
      active = active.previousElementSibling || active;
    } else {
      active = e.target;
    }
    active.classList.add("hover");
  }
}
```

```css
ul.dropdownItemContainer li.hover {
  background-color: #8284e6;
}

.dropdown-test {
  height: 90px;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown-test">
  <ul class="dropdownItemContainer">
    <li class="hover" data-checker>Item 1</li>
    <li data-checker>Item 2</li>
    <li data-checker>Item 3</li>
    <li data-checker>Item 4</li>
    <li data-checker>Item 5</li>
    <li data-checker>Item 6</li>
    <li data-checker>Item 5</li>
    <li data-checker>Item 6</li>
    <li data-checker>Item 2</li>
    <li data-checker>Item 3</li>
    <li data-checker>Item 4</li>
    <li data-checker>Item 5</li>
    <li data-checker>Item 6</li>
    <li data-checker>Item 5</li>
    <li data-checker>Item 6</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

If you want use data-attribute only into `<ul>` use this code:

```js
var active = document.querySelector(".hover") || document.querySelector(".dropdownItemContainer li");

document.addEventListener("keydown", handler);
document.addEventListener("mouseover", handler);

function handler(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let element = null;
  if (e.which === 40) {
    element = active.nextElementSibling;
  }
  if (e.which === 38) {
    element = active.previousElementSibling;
  }
  if ((e.target.parentElement && e.target.parentElement.hasAttribute("data-checker")) || (element && element.parentElement.hasAttribute("data-checker"))) {
      active.classList.remove("hover");
      if (e.which == 40) {
        active = active.nextElementSibling || active;
      } else if (e.which == 38) {
        active = active.previousElementSibling || active;
      } else {
        active = e.target;
      }
      active.classList.add("hover");
    }
  }
```

```css
ul.dropdownItemContainer li.hover {
  background-color: #8284e6;
}

.dropdown-test {
  height: 90px;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown-test">
  <ul class="dropdownItemContainer" data-checker>
    <li class="hover">Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: i just tired it on my Vue js app , the e.target.hasAttribute("data-checker") always false, is that any wrong ?

Comment: all `<li>` have that attribute?

Comment: You are welcome :) i add `<ul>` only checker into my solution.

Comment: oh ya , i got issue when doing key up and down after use data-checker, it doesnt work well, when i use scroll overflow auto

Comment: Is same as your example, can you create a equal example? or you have a live version?

Comment: https://codepen.io/lpllplp222/pen/powJggR?editors=1010 that is my code pen, and seem the trigger up and down become buggy after busing data-checker

Comment: id doesn't scroll to first and last, it gonna stuck on the middle only

Comment: if i check the hasAttribute tag on last conditional else , it was work, but the key and up jump per 2-3 times , not per one

Comment: I add a small change to second example, as you can see i check the next or prev element before the final script.

Comment: i made some modified on my own and had the same issue as your latest change, when u go on the last  ul li and then going up again with key up keyboard, it gonna jump not per one, but per 3-4 , such as i am on 10 to up , it gonna jump to 6 ul li

Comment: i see, m case is should be overflow :)

Comment: Fixed with best solution with overflow. (just add e.preventDefualt() for prevent overflow down instead of element)

Comment: it was not scrolling to down and up if the overflow auto

Comment: I need to see live version so